# Android TextView unwanted padding issue

Tags: android, textview, padding

[image: Unwanted padding on right side]

I am having issue with android TextView. having unwanted spacein TextView,
the space is coming only sometimes.  For your reference attached image above, you can see some extra space on the right end of TextView. Please help me guys. 
here is the xml code

```
  <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:padding="0dp"                     
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="@{message.message}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorLink="@android:color/white"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                tools:text="this is the  problem i am having please helpme to find a solution" />
```

Comment: We are not able to answer your question without code snippets. Post your required code.

Comment: If you will add the XML for your textView it will be easier to help you, please add it to make your question less broad.

Comment: are you using a 9-patch image for a bubble in the background?

Comment: yes @Priyankagb , but not for textview, I have a Framelayout  as parent of text view, 9-patch image is applied to the framelayout. in the image you can see the boundaries of text view.

Comment: and one more thing that if you are saying that padding after "please" than it's not padding. your "helme" word is not going to fit after "please" word, if you write a small word it goes to fit here

Comment: Ok, @Priyankagb sorry for that, i mean unwanted space. instead of padding.

Comment: you are saying that space after "please" and textView border is unwanted?

Comment: yes @Priyankagb

Comment: you can not manage this space if the word is not fitting in the previous line in normal `TextView`. You have to use JustfyTextView

Comment: @AnshadAliKM try with `android:justificationMode="inter_word"` (API26)

Comment: thanks @IntelliJAmiya it may work, but i have to support API versions prior to 26

Comment: use https://github.com/ufo22940268/android-justifiedtextview

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library to justify `textview`

https://github.com/navabi/JustifiedTextView

```
 <ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:padding="25dp"
    xmlns:noghteh="http://noghteh.ir"
    noghteh:text="text here"
    noghteh:textColor="@color/text"
    noghteh:textSize="18sp"/>
```